# How to skip an empty cell in a column?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

My column A has  values like 
kat1
kat2
empty
kat3
I would like the program to essentially skip the empty cell and use kat3 as the cell to set the last row(lrow). The code I am using is as seen below.
Below is the revised code:

```
Private Sub txt_BPName1_Exit(ByVal cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
 Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


    With ws

         Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
         'Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Select
         'Lrow = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row + 1
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & Lrow)

    End With

    For Each c In rng
        If c.Value = txt_BPName1 And c.Value <> "" Then
           MsgBox "Cell " & c.Address & " Duplicate Found."
              cancel = True


            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

     MsgBox ("Base Product is not duplicate,Ok to Add")

     Cells(Lrow + 1, 1).Value = txt_BPName1.Text

     txt_BPName1.Text = ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End Sub
```

The value is getting entered into empty cell instead of one below it.

Comment: What's wrong with `Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row`?

Comment: The error is because you're using `.Select` after trying to set it to a variable. Switch that with `.Row` instead.  But, that may not be (most likely not) the solution to your overall issue...That's just why that error is happening for you.  You could try doing `If c.Value = txt_BPName1 and c.Value <> "" Then`

Answer (score 1):

Simply add an if statement in your loop

```
For Each c In rng
    If not "" = c.Value Then
```

Comment: I'd personally flip that to make it a little more intuitive, `If c.Value <> "" Then ...`  Other than "If not blank is C Value" vs. "if c value is not blank, then"

Comment: @Abhi0609 - Can you instead edit that comment into your OP? It's hard to read code in the comments.